# Moving from mysql to postgresql in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Quick question for the Stackoverflow community- I've searched elsewhere and can't seem to find the answer.

If i want to move a rails app that hasn't went very far yet (no records in the tables yet) from mysql to postgresql, would it be fine to just connect to an empty postgresql database and rerun the migrations so the schemas match?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it would. :)  Change the adapter type in database.yml and you should be good to go.